# Chisq.test/prop.test on vectors of different lengths

Tags: r, data.table, chi-squared, proportions

I am trying to do a chisq.test or a prop.test on data where some patients are surgical and other are non-surgical. I want to see if the proportions of the two sexes are equal in both groups. What is the most appropriate test in this instance where my surgical and non-surgical group sizes are not equivalent?

I am trying to use the following code, using data.table but I get the error also found below:

```
> chisq.test(lateral[Surgery == "No", "sex",with=F], lateral[Surgery == "Yes", "sex",with=F])

Error in chisq.test(lateral[Surgery == "No", "sex", with = F], lateral[Surgery ==  : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length

For prop.test():
Error in complete.cases(x, n) : not all arguments have the same length
```

Data

```r
setDT(structure(list(sex = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Surgery = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" )), row.names = c(NA, -239L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" )))
```

Comment: Can you provide your data with `dput(your_df_goes_here)`?

Comment: Added! Thank you!

Comment: While it's not hard for us to clean up, when you post the `dput(.)` output for a `data.table`, it includes a component `.internal.selfref = <pointer: ...>` that cannot be used. I'm editing your question to remove that and wrap in `setDT(.)` so that it is effectively usable as-is. Please consider this with future questions. Thanks!

Comment: Bottom line: use `chisq.test(table(lateral))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a table to the function `chisq.test`, making it more simple. For example

```
df <- structure(list(sex = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                       2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                       1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                       1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                       2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                       1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                       2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                       2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                       2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                       1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                       2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                       2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Surgery = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"
                       )), row.names = c(NA, -239L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

df$sex <- as.factor(df$sex)
df$Surgery <- as.factor(df$Surgery)
(prop_table <- table(df))
# Surgery
# sex No Yes
# 1 97  66
# 2 57  19
mod1 <- chisq.test(prop_table)
mod1
# Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
# 
# data:  prop_table
# X-squared = 4.7727, df = 1, p-value = 0.02892
str(mod1)
# List of 9
# $ statistic: Named num 4.77
# ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "X-squared"
# $ parameter: Named int 1
# ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
# $ p.value  : num 0.0289
# $ method   : chr "Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction"
# $ data.name: chr "prop_table"
# $ observed : 'table' int [1:2, 1:2] 97 57 66 19
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. ..$ sex    : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
# .. ..$ Surgery: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
# $ expected : num [1:2, 1:2] 105 49 58 27
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. ..$ sex    : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
# .. ..$ Surgery: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
# $ residuals: 'table' num [1:2, 1:2] -0.783 1.147 1.055 -1.544
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. ..$ sex    : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
# .. ..$ Surgery: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
# $ stdres   : 'table' num [1:2, 1:2] -2.33 2.33 2.33 -2.33
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. ..$ sex    : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
# .. ..$ Surgery: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```